# Count number of cases and add row to sum average cost

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large data set that I'm trying to export in a way I've never done before. There are dozens of columns with flags (0 or 1) to indicate whether a person has that trait. At the end each record has a total cost which sums up all money associated with that person. Sample below

| ID | Visit | Stay | Treatment | Total Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | $50 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | $100 |

I'm trying to get it into a format like so:

| Visit | Stay | Treatment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| $100 | $50 | $75 |

So that number of flags is summed up per column and the average cost is below that. Hence, there's two treatment and the average cost is $75, there's one stay with an average cost of $100.

I've tried GROUPING BY and a few other functions, but haven't been successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We add up all we need and then use `union all` to `unpivot`.

```
select sum(visit)     as visit      
      ,sum(stay)      as stay
      ,sum(treatment) as treatment
from   t


union all 


select sum(visit*total_cost)/sum(visit)
      ,sum(stay*total_cost)/sum(stay)
      ,sum(treatment*total_cost)/sum(treatment)
from   t
```

| visit | stay | treatment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 100 | 50 | 75 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_RL4nrMq)